# Cpp compilation from python fail but not in the shell

Tags: python, c++, g++

I have a `cpp` file that compiles fine with `g++` by using the shell:

```
extern "C"{
  #include <quadmath.h>
}

inline char* print( const __float128& val)
{
  char* buffer = new char[128];
  quadmath_snprintf(buffer,128,"%+.34Qe", val);
  return buffer;
}
int main(){
    __float128 a = 1.0;
    print(a);
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I try to compile it via a `python` scrit, it fails with the following error:

> "undefined reference to quadmath_snprintf"

Here the code of the `python` script:

```
import commands
import string
import os
(status, output) = commands.getstatusoutput("(g++ test/*.c -O3 -lquadmath -m64)")
```

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Probably you don't have `LIBRARY_PATH` correctly set from python. Try use -L on g++ or export `LIBRARY_PATH` first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open a shell a whole of stuff is silently initialized for you, and most important for your issue, environment variables are set. What you most likely miss is the definition of `LIBRARY_PATH`, which is the variable used by the linker to look for libraries matching the ones you instruct it to link using the `-lNAME` flags.

What the linker needs is a list of directories where it will search for files matching `libNAME.{a,so}`. You can also pass these directories directly using the `-L` flag, but in general, you should probably try to use a program like CMake, Make or any other build tool.

This will give you access to commands like `find_package` and `target_link_libraries` (CMake), to find, respectively add libraries to your build targets, instead of having to maintain your python to compile your stuff.

Comment: `-L` option is looking for LIBRARY_PATH, not `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (that's for runtime). Fix your answer please.

Comment: I made the same mistake! ;) +1